# Join tables and project into a new model

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, join, razor

I am new to Linq. I have been using strongly typed data-sets but like the idea of Linq to create objects.

At the moment I use datasets to retrieve a table that joins data from tblProducts and tblProductSettings.

This is a one to many relationship as the products serve multiple websites with a unique tblSettings row for each website, however its assumed that there is always one row for tblSettings per website.

Example :

```
Select * from tblproducts, tblProductSettings where tblproducts.ProdID = tblProductSettings.ProdID and tblProductSettings.CreatorID = @CreatorID
```

The dataset will give a nice table to loop through and display the products with the settings.

Linq will give me a tblProducts object with tblProductSettings as a collection. I don't want to have to loop a collection each time to get the settings as this will, i believe create a new sql query for each product and make accesses the settings a pain.

I can create a custom object tblProductsAll, but the only way I can fill this object is...

```
var Product = from p in context.tblProducts
              join ps in context.tblProductSettings on p.ProdID equals ps.ProdID
              where p.CreatorID == 1 && ps.ProdCreatorDisplay == 1
              select new tblProductsAll() 
              { 
                   ProdTitle = p.ProdTitle,
                   ProdPrice = ps.ProdPrice
              };
```

I can then pass this model to the razor template.

My question is... is there a better way of setting the properties ? There are 20 or more different properties and i don't want to have to keep setting them, repeating code, every time i want the same object somehwere in the site with a differnt where clause.  Is there a way to stop this repetition ? i.e. automatically mapping the object, or reusing the select new statement.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want something like this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there are navigation properties, use them! Your `Product` entity has a navigation property `ProductSettings`. That means that the query could look like this:

```cs
var products = from p in context.Products
               from ps in p.ProductSettings
               where p.CreatorID == 1 && ps.ProdCreatorDisplay == 1
               select new ProductsAll() 
               { 
                    ProdTitle = p.ProdTitle,
                    ProdPrice = ps.FirstOrDefault().ProdPrice
               };
```

(Note that I stubbornly refuse to use the `tbl` prefix)

But that does not tackle the repetitive code issue.

Enter [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). This is a nice little tool that removes boilerplate property copying statement from your code by defining and executing mappings between objects. The default mapping is based on name convention. E.g. the statement `Mapper.CreateMap<Product,ProductDto>();` configures a mapping between all equally named properties of `Product` and `ProductDto`. And `Mapper.Map<ProductDto>(product);` would create a `ProductDto` object from `product`.

But your `ProductsAll` class has a property `ProdPrice` that comes from `ProductSettings`. How to deal with that?

Here a nice feature of AutoMapper can be used. It also resolves properties of nested objects based on name convention. Suppose your class `Product` had a property `Title`, AutoMapper can resolve that to a property `ProductTitle` in the target object. Let's use that:

```cs
class ProductsAll
{
    // ProductSetting should have a Product property.
    public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
    // Assuming ProductSetting has a property ProdPrice.
    public decimal ProdPrice { get; set; }
}

...

Mapper.CreateMap<ProductSetting,ProductsAll>(); // ProductSetting!

var q = from ps in context.ProductSettings
        where ps.Product.CreatorID == 1 && ps.ProdCreatorDisplay == 1;

// Now the magic!
var products = q.Project().To<ProductsAll>();
```

`Project()` is an extension method on `IQueryable`. The nice thing is that the SQL statement only contains the properties used in the projection. As you see, you can define a mapping once and for the rest use the `Project().To()` construct in your code.

There's much more to AutoMapper. This is a quick start.

Comment: Automapper sounds like the thing for me. Its the kind of thing you would have thought there was built in support for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged this [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), I'm guessing you are using Entity Framework.  In that case, you can tell linq it to load the settings for your products without explicitly specifying the join.  I'm assuming here your products has a relationship to your product settings table which is exposed via a Settings property on your product entity.

```
var allProducts = context.tblProducts
    .Where(p => p.CreatorID == 1 && p.Settings.ProdCreatorDisplay == 1)
    .Include(p = p.Settings)
    .Select(p => CreateViewModelFromFullyPopulatedProductModel(p))
    .ToList();
```

Once you have the full settings loaded, you can just write a mapping function that does the mapping for you.  Of course this will load **all** of the properties of the products and the settings for each of those products.  That can be a major concern depending on how many products you are loading and how many unused properties they have, but from your question, it sounds like you are loading most of these values for the view model already.

Comment: I am using entity framework. I assume that because technically there could be a one to many relationship with the settings table, the entity framework has added it into the the tblProduct model as  ICollection<tblProductSetting>. I really want a model that maybe has half of the columns from tblProducts and half the columns from tblSettings. My knowledge of linq is only a couple of days old, but form what i have read, tblproducts is called, then it runs a new sql  query when i try to access ICollection<tblProductSetting>. This seams very Inefficient when selectng and displaying 40 + products.

Comment: When you use the Include function, it preloads the values from that table for each item it loads.  If you access the properties in a query, it will create joins for you in the underlying sql that gets generated and only run a single query.  If you have already materialized the product, then calling the settings property would execute a new query.  It is possible to see the sql that gets generated so you can verify it's doing what you want and not an N+1, but you'll have to look up how to grab it.

Comment: If i understand this correct. The Tolist() and the .include will join the tables and load them up front in a single query. CreateViewModelFromFullyPopulatedProductModel(p) is a custom function to loop the products object and load in into the new ProductsAll Object? Thank you for your help.